# web applications, dynamic charts and simulation tools? (for MATLAB users)

Tags: matlab, web-applications, simulation, matlab-deployment

We are a group of students of chemical engineering mostly proficient in MATLAB and Simulink but with almost no clue of web programming.

Our idea is to develop some online examples by using interactive graphics with dynamic effects and 2D/3D simulations. We know that MATLAB has some solutions but the compilers are not available for the student version. Furthermore, we want to promote the use of free open source alternatives (SciLab, Octave, NumPy)

Ideally, we would like to use a [4GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) which includes a free library for numeric analysis and combine it with graphic user interface framework for web applications.

An good example will be [Easy Java Simulations](http://www.um.es/fem/EjsWiki/Main/WhatIsEJS?) that generates java code and can be easily implemented online. However, we are looking for something that can be executed without java or another plugin (see [google chart tool](https://developers.google.com/chart/))

Although we are willing to learn (Python, Java), we would like to start with the easiest solution towards a painless transition for a chemical engineer ;)

We will really appreciate our recommendations and suggestions!

Comment: Almost two years have been past from this question. If you are reading this because you want to do something similar, take a look to [IPython Notebook / Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) and the gorgeous example of
[Nature: IPython interactive demo](http://www.nature.com/news/ipython-interactive-demo-7.21492?article=1.16261)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best shot is to buy the product `Matlab Builder NE`. You can use [WebFigures](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/description1.html) to seamlessly create web applications from your Matlab application.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out but the problem of this solution is that the user might install MCR. 
We are trying to migrate to a free open source distribution.

Comment: @FZNB, MCR does not cost money, its free to deploy

Comment: MCR doesnt but the compiler does. 
Unfortunately, we can not afford the costs of MATLAB as students. The idea is to encourage other fellows by using free and open source alternatives